# Checking if user name exists in database using a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a stored procedure to insert employee information. But it should return whether an employee with a given name already exists in the database or not, so that the user cannot register with the same employee name twice.

```
alter proc str_insertInfo
    @name nvarchar(30),
    @dob date,
    @department_id int,
    @description nvarchar(500),
    @gender char(10),
    @hobby int,
    @image nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    DECLARE @count int
    If exists (select count(emp_name) from employee_info where emp_name = @name)   
    Begin

        Set @count = 1
        return @count

    End     
    Else   
    begin

        Set @count = 0
        insert into employee_info
        values (@name, @dob, @department_id, isnull(@description, 'no description'),
            @gender, isnull(@hobby, 'no hobby'), isnull(@image, 'no image'))

    End

    Return @count

end
```

Comment: Please edit your question with SQL server version, sample data, table structure, previous code attempts.

Comment: @JohnHC please check above code and give suggestion

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckUsername(
   @Username VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE Column_name = @Username)

END
```

Edited with SQL Server syntax. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` clause:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE Column_name = Inputparameter(ie:user 
name))
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('UserName already exists', 16, 1)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variable as output in SP & get its value into code & display messages according to result

DECLARE @Result INT = 0 OUTPUT

SET @Result = **1** --Success
SET @Result = **0** --Error
SET @Result = **2** --Already Exist

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 'x' FROM table
                WHERE Condition )
    BEGIN

        SET @Result = 2
        RETURN

    END
```

Note: In Code set parameter direction as **ParameterDirection.Output**

Answer (score 0):

your query is correct. The issue is that you used count(emp_name). This always returns a row. It might be zero too, but exists only checks if there is a row.

That is why your query failed. And I assume, it always returned 1. If you remove the count, it should work fine.

Naz